# How to close all the open application on windows using java?

Tags: java, windows

I have made a package of exe installer of the following code to close all the open application on windows platform.
The exe is working fine on the machine on which its is written i.e. Windows 8.1 Pro (32 bit OS / X64 based processor)
But the same exe is not working on Windows 7 or different machine.

```
try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.toLowerCase().contains(".exe".toLowerCase()) && line.toLowerCase().contains("Console".toLowerCase())) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    String pocessKill = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(".exe"));
                    pocessKill = pocessKill + ".exe";

                    if (pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("netbeans.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("java.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("csrss.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("winlogon.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("dwm.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("taskhostex.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("explorer.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("igfxtray.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("hkcmd.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("igfxpers.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("jusched.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("GWX.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("rundll32.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("conhost.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("tasklist.exe") || pocessKill.equalsIgnoreCase("conhost.exe")) {
                        System.out.println(pocessKill);
                    } else {
                        rt.exec("taskkill /F /IM " + pocessKill);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Bad Process");
                }

            }
            input.close();

            System.out.println(rt.toString());

        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
```

On windows 8 its working fine, but on windows 7 its showing exceptions as follows:
(Output + Exception)

```
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
csrss.exe                      936 Console                    1     22,612 K
csrss.exe
Bad Process
winlogon.exe                  1016 Console                    1      3,508 K
winlogon.exe
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
dwm.exe                       1928 Console                    1     33,116 K
dwm.exe
explorer.exe                  1944 Console                    1     60,328 K
explorer.exe
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
Bad Process
PWRISOVM.EXE                  2152 Console                    1      3,456 K
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1955)
    at decryptomediaplayer.DecryptoMediaPlayer.main(DecryptoMediaPlayer.java:731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:238)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:224)
    at javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog$1.<init>(HeavyweightDialog.java:50)
    at javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.<init>(HeavyweightDialog.java:50)
    at javafx.scene.control.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:262)
    at javafx.scene.control.Alert.<init>(Alert.java:245)
    at javafx.scene.control.Alert.<init>(Alert.java:223)
    at decryptomediaplayer.DecryptoMediaPlayer.main(DecryptoMediaPlayer.java:750)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application decryptomediaplayer.DecryptoMediaPlayer
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What do you mean with `is not working`? Any error message? What is your desired result? To kill all `Console` processes returned by `tasklist | findstr Console | findstr ".exe"` except your exclusion list?

Comment: @SubOptimal : I just want to close all the running application from my java  application.

Comment: Ok. Then answer the other questions too. What do you mean with `is not working`? Any error message?

Comment: No error is shown. Can you provide me some code, so that I can close all the open application except my application.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to kill a program your user do not have the necessary user rights? Without any more information how you deside it is not working it will be hard for further help.

Comment: @SubOptimal: I have edited the question, please have a look at exception.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. Your code cannot handle processes in uppercase letters.

```
String line = "PWRISOVM.EXE   2152 Console";
String pocessKill = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(".exe"));
```

this will lead into

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the exception at this line:

```
  String pocessKill = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(".exe"));
```

The problem I see here is that the name PWRISOVM.EXE could not be converted to lower case and thus it could not find ".exe" as a result it gave an exception for

```
    line.substring(0, line.indexOf(".exe"));
```

There are multiple possibilities for this error. I would suggest you to give some more debugging information so that you can narrow the question. 
Firstly, you can check the java version in which you created your exe and the java version of the machine you are trying to run it on. 
Secondly, try debugging your code step by step using the debug options in any standard IDE like Eclipse.

You can edit your question after trying these things and provide more info about your problem. Also post what is your input.